# JQuery find closest to sibling div

Tags: jquery

for the following:

```
                    <div class="section">
                        <div class="row infoOn">
                            <div class="itemWrap clearfix">
                                <div class="itemTop clearfix">
                                </div>
                                <label class="">File title:</label>
                                <div class="inputWrap clearfix">
                                    <input type="text" class="text inpButton" value="upload file first" disabled="true"/>
                                    <a id="fileUpload" href="#" class="button">Browse</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- filelist -->
                        <div class="row uploadList">
                            <div class="itemWrap clearfix">
                                <label>&nbsp;</label>
                                <div class="inputWrap clearfix" style="position:relative;">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><span class="qq-upload-file">companyPic.png</span><span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span><span class="qq-upload-size" style="display: none;"></span><a href="#" class="qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</a><span class="qq-upload-failed-text">Failed</span></li>
                                        <li><span class="qq-upload-file">companyPic.png</span><span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span><span class="qq-upload-size" style="display: none;"></span><a href="#" class="qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</a><span class="qq-upload-failed-text">Failed</span></li>
                                        <li><span class="qq-upload-file">untitled.bmp</span><span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span><span class="qq-upload-size" style="display: none;"></span><a href="#" class="qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</a><span class="qq-upload-failed-text">Failed</span></li>
                                        <li><span class="qq-upload-file">This i...Document.docx</span><span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span><span class="qq-upload-size" style="display: none;"></span><a href="#" class="qq-upload-cancel">Cancel</a><span class="qq-upload-failed-text">Failed</span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- // file list -->
</div>
```

how do i select 'ul' element in "div.uploadlist" in relation to

```
    var button = $('#fileUpload')[0];
    alert($(button).closest('div.row').find('.uploadList ul').html());
```

??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use e.g. `$(button).closest('div.row').next('.uploadList').find('ul')`

Answer (score 2):

```
var button = $('#fileUpload');
alert(button.closest('div.row').next("div.uploadList ul").html());
```

You don't have to get the HTML object and then wrap again it to jQUery object.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the corresponding infoOn and uploadList in their own div. In your example that may be div.section. Then, find the div.section parent of the div.infoOn and find the uploadList within that parent.