# How do I target an anchor element in a previous division, via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target an anchor element in the previous division based on the click of a radio button in a subsequent division:

```
<li>
    <div class="list-item-name">
        <a href="#level-1" data-folder-child="26" data-folder-parent="0">Just a Folder</a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item-radio">
        <input type="radio" value="26" name="folders[]" id="list-item-radio-26">
    </div>
</li>
```

I've got to the division class "list-item-name" but I can't get at the anchor:

```
$(".folders-hierarchy").delegate("input[type=radio]", "click", function() {
    if (obj_radio.previous) {
        $("#" + obj_radio.previous).closest('li div.list-item-name a').css({ 'color': 'blue' });
        $("#" + obj_radio.previous).closest('li').css({ 'background-color': 'white' });
    }
    $(this).closest('li div.list-item-name a').css({ 'color': 'blue' });
    $(this).closest('li').css({ 'background-color': '#ffe7e7' });
    obj_radio.previous = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Here, I'm swapping the styles of various elements to reflect the choices being made, restoring earlier selections to their original styles.

Unfortunately, I can't show the whole of the code because it's tied to database data, which I can't reduce.

Comment: $(this).parent('li').find('a')

Comment: Close, but you got me thinking. It's: .closest('li').find('a')

Comment: $('.list-item-radio').prev().find('a');

Comment: In this case both are correct :) But you are right, closest() will find one specified parent

Comment: see this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921068/jquery-find-closest-to-sibling-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this -

```
$(this).closest('li div.list-item-name a')
```

jQuery tries to find closest `a` among the parents, which isn't available in your code -

You need to do this instead

```
$(this).closest('li').find('div.list-item-name a');
```

this will find the closest `li` and then look for `a` inside of that `li`

Demo to demonstrate this `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/jJWs2/

Answer (score 2):

I would get the anchor in the **previous** element like [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPVPn/).

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('a');
```